Compositum normal when only one field assumed normal
Could someone please help to clarify this point concerning normality and the compositum of field extensions?:
If $L_1/K$, $L_2/K$ are field extensions, and we only have the assumption that $L_1/K$ is normal (no statement regarding the normality of $L_2/K$), can we conclude that the compositum $L_1L_2/K$ is normal?
(If both $L_1/K$, $L_2/K$ are assumed normal, then we know $L_1L_2/K$ is normal, by considering the characterization of normal extensions in terms of any element of the extension having its minimal polynomial split into linear factors in the extension. This is considered, for example, here: Compositum of normal extensions is normal)

What do you think? :)

No. Take $K = \mathbb{Q}$, $L_1 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and $L_2 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. Then $L_1 / K$ is normal but $L_2 / K$ is not, and neither is $L_1 . L_2 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}) / K$: For the minimal polynomial $X^3 - 2$ to split over either $L_2$ or $L_1 . L_2$, these extensions would need to contain a primitive 3rd root of unity, but both of them are subfields of $\mathbb{R}$.

A simple and convincing example.

Thanks so much @Ben Steffan. This concrete example is very helpful. I realized I was misunderstanding the relationships of $L_1$ and $L_2$ to $L_1L_2$. In this example, $L_2\subset L_1L_2$ is normal, because it is a degree-2 extension. Is this true, in general, that $K \subset L_1$ normal implies $L_2\subset L_1L_2$ is normal?

I think your example demonstrates that $L_2\subset L_1L_2$ is normal, because if $L_1 = K(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$, then $L_1L_2 = L_2(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$, so the minimal polynomial generating the extension  $L_2\subset L_1L_2$ has all its roots ($\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$) in $L_1L_2$. Is this correct?

@J.. Yes, that would be correct.

Thanks @Ben Steffan. I had not understood this before.
